# Tkinter object has no attribute, sometimes work, sometimes no?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code like below (simplified), I can not run refresh method of Root widget, but I have the same system in a different program and it works. I wrote it 3 times in different files and sometimes it works, and sometimes does not. Maybe I am doing something wrong about creating this attr `self.a`, so please tell me how to do it so it would work always.

*Error:*

> `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'a'`

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text="some text").pack()
        self.master.refresh()

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def refresh(self):
        self.a.destroy()
        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()

Root()
```

Comment: `Window.__init__()` is calling `refresh()` _before_ `Root.__init__()` has finished initializing the `Tk` subclass instance.

Comment: and what can I do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, just your structure do not. Hope you can deal with a button.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Label(self, text="some text").pack()
        b = Button(self, text='refresh', command =lambda:self.master.refresh())
        b.pack()


class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def refresh(self):
        self.a.destroy()
        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()

Root()
```

**edit**

```
from tkinter import *
#this is the tricky version, lambda will not show any error if a error occurs

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def refresh(self):
        self.a.destroy()
        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()

def function():
    print('I am the executing function')
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Label(self, text="some text").pack()
        b = Button(self, text='refresh', command =lambda:[self.master.refresh(),self.func(), function()])        
        b.pack()
    def func(self):
        print('I am the executing func')


Root()

from tkinter import *
#this is the safer exampel, cause if a error occurs you will notice.

class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def refresh(self):
        self.a.destroy()
        self.a = Window(self)
        self.a.pack()

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Label(self, text="some text").pack()
        b = Button(self, text='refresh', command =self.func)
        b.pack()
    def func(self):
        self.master.refresh()

Root()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, now it make sense why sometimes it works and sometimes no.please tell me why it works as button command and why not like i wrote it

Comment: cause your function destroy your window before it is created. even programs need time to do their stuff.

Comment: Ok, but when i use self.master.refresh() i want to take other actions too, but i can not pack more functions into lamda function. When i try to call some function as button command, which contains self.master.refresh, it gives me error

Comment: can you put __self.master.refresh()__ into that function too? Otherwihsie you can add more than one function to lambda. But lambda is a bit tricky to debugg later, think first if you can put that command to that function too.

Comment: if i do it, it returns error, so i will put all stuff i needed into self.master.refresh method, it will be harder, but i do not know how to do it other way, my code now works, so thank you, but i still do not understand what happened, maybe i will know after more coding

Comment: edited my the answer, look if you find a solution for you

Comment: @katek1094 It would be nice if you accept my answer after it solved your problem.